# How to copy or duplicate a sheet from xlsm but also copying formatation, macros, etc.?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, win32com, xlsm

I need to create a new sheet in a xlsm file that's a copy from another sheet from that same xlsm.
That's kinda easy but the problem's that when I copy it, it won't copy the formatation and macros as well.
And they're the main reason I want to copy it.

[Original Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqf4q.png)

I've tryed the following:

```
import win32com.client


excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
book = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Users\lbsme\Desktop\reprogramacao\modelo.xlsm", UpdateLinks=0)
model = excel.Worksheets('model')

sheet1 = book.Worksheets.Add()
sheet1.Name = 'Copy'
sheet1 = book.Worksheets('Copy')

model.Range("A1:CF128").Copy()
sheet1.Paste(sheet1.Range('A1'))
```

And it works... kind of...
It does copy the formulas and part of the formatation but it does not copy the whole formatations or the buttons.

[Copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6tpC.png)

Also, while copying, it shows the same error messenge over and over again and I have no idea why since there's no other sheets besides the ones shown.
Even if I click "yes to all" it will show the messenge again and again.
I click it about eleven times.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmuwt.png)

I need my copies to be exatly like the model, including the buttons.
How to copy or duplicate the whole sheet perfectly?

Answer (score -1):

This simple code copies the whole sheet

```
Sheets("mysheet").Copy After:=Sheets("myothersheet")
```

Either way I guess you already know that you can just right-click on the sheet tab and then click on *"Move or copy"*

I don't see the point on copying the macros if it's in the same workbook....
If you want to copy paste the macros' code to modify one of them you could just copy-paste it or if it's really something that you do regularly enough and it's repetitive you could just use a python library to write macros or... I found this to duplicate vba code directly from excel:

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3126412/how-can-i-create-a-script-or-macro-to-duplicate-and-rename-a-tab-for-each-day-in-a-month?hl=en

If this was helpful please set this as the proper answer! :)
Have a nice one!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your context
Sheets("mysheet").Copy After:=Sheets("myothersheet")
Whats 'Sheets'? A variable or maybe an object?
Is "After:=" a typo or it's actually something?